# Way to measure time of execution program

Tags: c, linux

I have a lots of short programs in C. Each program realize simple operation for example: include library, load something (ex matrix) from file, do simple operation, write matrix to file end.

I want to measure real time of excecution a whole program (not only fragment of code).

My simple idea is using htop or ps aux -> column time. But this method isn't good because I don't have exacly time of execution but time of excecution during last refresh and I can miss this.

Do you have any method to measure time of process in linux?

Comment: you can always use the `time` builtin of your shell: `time ./yourprogram`

Comment: Actually, it is better to change the programs or their inputs so that they run for a few seconds. If your program only need some milliseconds to complete, the measures will be very inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your program is named foo, then simply typing

```
~$ time foo
```

should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers, mostly suggesting to use the `time` utility or shell builtins:

- [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) is a very useful page to read.
- You might use (inside your code) the [clock(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/clock.3.html) standard function to get CPU time in microseconds.
- Resolution and accuracy of time measures depends upon hardware and operating system kernel. You could prefer a "real-time" kernel (e.g. a `linux-image-3.2.0-rt` package), or at least a kernel configured with `CONFIG_HZ_1000`) to get more precise time measures.
- You might also use (inside your code) the [clock_gettime(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) syscall (so link also the `-lrt` library).
- When doing measurements, try to have your measured process run a few seconds at least, and measure it several times (because e.g. of disk cache issues).

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
time <PROGRAM> [ARGS]
```

this will provide some base-level information. This should run your shell's time command. Example output:

```
$ time sleep 2
real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But there is also

```
/usr/bin/time <PROGRAM> [ARGS]
```

which is more flexible and provides considerably more diagnostic information regarding timing. This runs a GNU timing program. [This site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/time-command-examples/) has some usage examples. Example output:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v sleep 2
Command being timed: "sleep 2"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:02.00
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2496
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 202
Voluntary context switches: 2
Involuntary context switches: 1
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Comment: Adding little things to it... You can also do  "man time" to know more about arguments and options with time command ...Whatever Richard mentioned is correct btw